# How to get the radius to get the volume of the figure?

Tags: geometry

I have this statement:

> In the tube of the attached figure, the segment AC is tangent at A to
>   the circumference inside. The volume of the tube can be determined, if
>   it is known that:
>
> (1) The measurement of the AC segment is 5 cm. (2) The length of the
>   tube is 80 cm.

[image]

With $2)$ I can't because i need to get the radius,

With $1)$ Maybe there is a relationship to get the radio, but I would miss the length.

With $1), 2)$ together, I think that is possible, but my problem is that, I don't know how to find the radius given the tangent $AC = 5$

PD: The correct answer must be 1, 2 together

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Can you find an expression for the volume given the inner radius (OA) and the outer radius (OC)?  Then, can you find a relationship with OA and OC given that AC=5?

Comment: $OC = \sqrt{25 + OA^2}$, but i dont have $OA$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tough part is finding the area of the annulus.  Obviously, it is the area of the larger circle minus the area of the inner circle, which is $\pi(OC^2-OA^2)$.  But, by the Pythagorean Theorem, we know that $OC^2-OA^2=AC^2=25$.  Therefore, the area of the annulus is $25\pi$ cm and thus the volume of the pipe is $25\pi\cdot 80=2000\pi\mathrm{\ cm^3}$.

Comment: thanks, My mistake was to think that I should calculate the volume of the entire cylinder